# What is maximum query size for mysql?

Tags: mysql, wamp

What is maximum query size for mysql? Some times the server stops working when I fire a too long query.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Answer (score 229):

You can check your current
server setting with:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

This gives you the answer in bytes. for e.g `max_allowed_packet=1048576` or `1 MiB`

Comment: If it's in bytes, then the 1mb from answer is about 8 times smaller.

Comment: It seems that this answer implies that the maximum query length is only limited by the maximum packet size that can be sent to the server. This basically means that there is no upper limit to query lengths as long as you're able to send it to the server.

Answer (score 39):

To increase the `max_allowed_packet`, open

`my.ini/my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` section.

Once the change is done you would have to restart the server.

Comment: Using "128MB", "1GB", etc is allowed. The value does not have to be in bytes (but it is supported). Max value is 1GB. If you set it to more than 1GB, mysql will still start normally, but it will not accept anything over 1GB.