# Random 1000 times on a refresh by Using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have create a generate random in php and insert into mysql already. But I want to loop it 1000 times when I refresh for one time. All item must go to store in database. How can I do this?

```
function generateCode($length = 11) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
echo $lucky_code=generateCode()."<br/>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "random";

$cnt = mysql_pconnect($servername, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_code(code) VALUES('$lucky_code')",$cnt) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you can set -->for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) instead of $length use 1000

Comment: @syedmohamed or he can call his exiting function with `1000` passed as the argment, since he already observes the default argument anyway. What is the error you receive, Chheang?

Comment: @syedmohamed This is my length digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set_time_limit` before the code and run loop 1000 times as below

```
set_time_limit(0);

function generateCode($length = 11) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "random";

$cnt = mysql_pconnect($servername, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $lucky_code = generateCode();
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_code(code) VALUES('".$lucky_code."')", $cnt) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: it works but all the items are the generate code. Is there any way to make it different from each item?

Comment: Is it generating same string for all records?

Comment: Yes, it is. Every record must be different.

Comment: I have used your way, check the edits and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    $lucky_code = generateCode();

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_code(code) VALUES('$lucky_code')",$cnt) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

If your [maximum query size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335011/what-is-maximum-query-size-for-mysql) is big enough you can also try to add all rows in one query so that there is only one query (instead of 1000 queries):

```
$lucks_codes = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $lucky_codes[] = generateCode();
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_code(code) VALUES ('".implode("'), ('", $lucky_codes)."')", $cnt) or die(mysql_error());
```

Please also keep in mind that the [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is deprecated. Please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: would second option add 1000 times?

Comment: Yes, it would generate something like `INSERT INTO tbl_code(code) VALUES ('...'), ('...'), ('...'), ('...'), ('...'), ('...'), ...`