# How to check the current query packet size for MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

According to the answer to this question: [What is maximum query size for mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335011/what-is-maximum-query-size-for-mysql)

The max value is shown in bytes and not characters, so I can't decide when the time to split the query is. Would be even better if I could check that while the query is still a string in php since its length will be flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `strlen()` to measure the byte size of your query in php.

See manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

> Note:
>   strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.