# Is there a limit on how many arguments I can pass to MySQL where clause?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

we need to construct a Mysql query with lots of conditions:

```
where userId=useIdi1 or userId=userId2 or userId=userId3....
```

I know I can use IN instead but just curious if there is any limit on how many parameters(arguments) we can pass to WHERE clause in MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no limit specifically to the number of conditions, but in practice there is a limit to query length.

See: [What is maximum query size for mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335011/what-is-maximum-query-size-for-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can find the size with the parameter:
max_allowed_packet