# mysql select throwing error as Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a simple select query . I'm getting the `amount` by `companyID` . I have more than 200 companies.. when i run this for all company its throwing error as

> Can't write; duplicate key in table
>   'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp#sql1504_ebd2_12b'

but if run for 100 companies its working fine.. but this only happening in server in my local it's working fine

Below i have mentioned how im getting `amount` by `companyID`.

```
SELECT SUM( IF ( companyID = 'OC', CYC, 0 ) ) AS CY_OC,
       SUM( IF ( companyID = 'OC1', CYC, 0 ) ) AS CY_OC1 ,
       ....200 More
FROM fntable
GROUP BY typeID
```

Comment: Since it's a simple select query you might as well publish it all.

Comment: What do you get when `select companyID from yourTable group by companyID having count(*)>1` is issued (of course whenever 200 companies included)

Comment: I'm getting the companyID those 200 .  I dont't have any issue in my local . only in server . if selecting length exceeding certain limit causing this problem

Comment: Are you running out of disk space due to some kind of logging enabled?

Comment: No . have enough of disk space

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help? 
[What is maximum query size for mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335011/what-is-maximum-query-size-for-mysql)

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Comment: Maybe you can try with 120, 140, 160 companies to  get the maximum accepted length?